# Qt/Qml Quick Control 2: SpinBox value without number format

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to display numbers in a Qml Quick Controls 2 `SpinBox` without number formatting:

```
SpinBox {
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
    from: 1000
    to: 10000
}
```

I tried to set different locales but everytime the number is displayed as "1.000" or "1,000" (correct would be "1000"). Is there a way to force the unformatted output?

Comment: For readers that stumble across this question, a related but different question on number formatting for spinboxes: [**How to use Float in a QML SpinBox**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406830/how-to-use-float-in-a-qml-spinbox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the [`textFromValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html#textFromValue-prop) function:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true

    SpinBox {
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
        from: 1000
        to: 10000

        textFromValue: function(value) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```